# How to resume sending emails with smtplib and multipe smtps?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtplib

**Hello beauful people ,  i hope your day is doing awesome**

- I have a text file with my marketing emails list seperated with lines
  like this : example1@gmail.com example2@yahoo.com example@hotmail.com

  and i have 4 smtp server linked to my cpanel from i send my marketing
  emails !!

  Well i can import smtps from file to my code and it connects to the
  first smtp in the list and starts sending and when one smtp is down
  or timeout it goes to the next smtp **BUT** starting from the top of
  the mail list again ,it does not continue from where the first smtp
  stopped in the mail list .

This is from my code  :

> Function to grab my smtps from text file :

```
def checker(file):
    with open(file, "r") as f:
         lines = f.readlines()
         for line in lines:
             smtp_server, smtp_port, smtp_user, smtp_pass = line.rstrip('\n').split("|")
```

> Function to generate message for every email :

```
def generate_messages(recipients):
    with open(letter_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
         data = myfile.read()
         for recipient in recipients:
             message = EmailMessage()
             message['Subject'] = letter_subject
             message['From'] = Address(letter_From, *smtp_user.split("@"))
             message['To'] = recipient
             message.set_content(data, 'html')
             yield message
```

> Function of sending

```
def smtp(smtp_server, port, user, password, messages):
    with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
         try:
            server.ehlo()
            server.starttls()
            server.ehlo()
            server.login(user, password)
            print(crayons.green(f'Connected to smtp : {smtp_server}\n'''))
            for message in messages:
                server.send_message(message)
                print(Fore.GREEN +'\n[+]', message['To'] + f''' SENT!{time.strftime('%X')}''')
                time.sleep(10)
          except smtplib.SMTPException:
                 print(crayons.red(f'''smtp died \nSERVER : {smtp_server}\n'''))
```

> i have thought about it a lot and i still can't find it how to let the
> next smtp continue continue from where the first one stopped !!
>
> thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

- The answer is easy apparently !!!
- we just have to add

`recipients.remove(recipient)`

under the `message['To'] = recipient`

now we delete the recepient from the existance when the message is sent!